# How can I access the value defined inside the cy.get() in cypress/Typescript?

Tags: typescript, cypress

I need to access the value of the getLength function. It is returning undefined value. How can I access the value here?

My code is:

```
const verifyValue = () => {
  const selector = 'nz-option-container nz-option-item';
  const myActualLength = getLength(selector);
  console.log('I need to access this value :' + myActualLength);
}

const getLength = (selector: string) => {
  let length;
  cy.get(selector).then((listItem) => {
    length = listItem.length;
  })
  return length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
This is how I am able to acces the value:

const getLength = (selector: string) => {
  let length;
  cy.get(selector).then((listItem) => {
    length = listItem.length;
  })
  return cy.wrap(length);
}

getLength(selector).then(value => {
  console.log('I need to access this value :' + value );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about cypress (and javascript callbacks), you will need to return the value from inside of .then(). If you try to access the value from outside of that function, it will return undefined.

So maybe try:

```
cy.get(selector).then((listItem) => {
   return listItem.length;
})
```